How to apply AppArmor profile to pipx binaries?
I'm working with a tool that uses user namespaces. On Ubuntu 24.04.1 this requires setting up a profile as documented here. That works great when I run the tool directly. However, that tool actually recommends installation via pipx. When I apply the profile as per the linked documentation, permissions errors come back.
I think this is because pipx is running the tool via some indirection that breaks the connection to the AppArmor profile.
Here's the profile resulting from my failed attempt:
❯❯  sudo cat /etc/apparmor.d/home.brendan..local.bin.mkosi 
abi <abi/4.0>,

include <tunables/global>

/home/brendan/.local/bin/mkosi flags=(default_allow) {
        include <abstractions/base>
        include <abstractions/python>

        userns,
}

And here's how the logs look in dmesg when I try to run the binary from ~/.local/bin:
[   38.920086] audit: type=1400 audit(1735497818.562:201): apparmor="AUDIT" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="Userns create - transitioning profile" profile="unconfined" pid=3579 comm="python" requested="userns_create" target="unprivileged_userns"
[   38.921382] audit: type=1400 audit(1735497818.563:202): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="unprivileged_userns" pid=3579 comm="python" capability=21  capname="sys_admin"
[   38.954480] audit: type=1400 audit(1735497818.598:203): apparmor="AUDIT" operation="userns_create" class="namespace" info="Userns create - transitioning profile" profile="unconfined" pid=3581 comm="python" requested="userns_create" target="unprivileged_userns"

Anyone know if there's a way to do something like this?

I noticed the docs say to raise a bug so I raised one for the topic of the pipx/userns issue. But this question can probably still generally be useful for people to learn about AppArmor.
